# Scrapy startproject PermissionError

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler

I'm trying to learn web scraping and creating my first WebSpider but I got this error in the very first step.
When trying to create the project this message appears together with a pop-up from my antivirus saying the action was blocked.
Do I need to configure anything before installing/starting Scrapy?

I've tried to look at similar questions in StackOverFlow but didn't find anything helpful.

thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: you don't have write access to that directory .. check your access level

Comment: went down on folder properties=>security and granted write permission for all users, still not working.